# Spring cloud gateway and outh2

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a legacy web application that I want to secure it by using a Spring cloud gateway with Outh2.
Without Outh2, the Spring cloud gateway worked with the following application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: my_route
          uri: http://MyLegacyServer:8080
          predicates:
            - Path=/**
```

But when I added the keycloak definition to it like the following

```
keycloak:
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8083/auth
  realm: xxx
  resource: login-app
  public-client: true
```

I was getting the following error when at start

Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayClassPathWarningAutoConfiguration$SpringMvcFoundOnClasspathConfiguration': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayClassPathWarningAutoConfiguration$SpringMvcFoundOnClasspathConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.MvcFoundOnClasspathException

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used keycloak before but when you look at the nested exception within the one that says the application couldn't start because a bean could not be instantiated, you see **MvcFoundOnClasspathException**.
Spring Cloud gateway is a reactive framework. It is in opposition to the Spring Mvc model. ["The main difference between the two frameworks is that spring-mvc is based on thread pools, while spring-webflux is based on event-loop mechanism."](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/12/servlet-reactive-stack/)
If you want to protect a resource using oauth, [Spring Security is webflux-compatible](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jc-webflux.html).